# When is the database engine created in flask sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Does the Flask-Sqlalchemy extension connect on every request to the remote database or only once when flask app starts? When does this extension call create_engine() from sqlalchemy package? I can't find this in source code of Flask-SqlAlchemy on github.

Answer (score 1):

In Flask-SQLAlchemy, the database engine is created when you initialize the SQLAlchemy object. It creates the database engine when the application context is created, which usually happens once per application instance, and not on every request.

It uses a connection pool to manage connections to the database. When the application starts, the connection pool is initialized with a certain number of connections, which are used to handle incoming requests.

The engine gets created on the _make_engine() method of the SQLAlchemy class on the extension.py file which has been renamed from create_engine(). This function gets called on the init_app() method.